# Angular 2 animations : per element transition time

Tags: angular, css-animations

Take the following case:
I have a list of items created using an *ngFor loop. I would like them to appear sequentially one by one (in opposition to all of them as one) using an animation

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" [@flyInOut]="'in'">
```

But then when I create the animation, (using the void state of the primary state of each of those div), they all inherit from the same initial / final state. Therefore they will appear all as one instead of sequentially.

```
animations: [
  trigger('flyInOut', [
    state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
    transition('void => *', [
      style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
      animate(100)
    ]),
    transition('* => void', [
      animate(100, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
    ])
  ])
]
```

I wish to be able to specify a delay as we can do it using [animation delay](http://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp)
And this delay to be specified with the ngFor loop but I had no luck with making it work. As I only have a limited numbe of instance, I thought of hardcoding the trigger (for instance building flyInOut1, flyInOut1,…) but this is really a bad practice.

Any better solution?

Comment: Okay it looks like staggering animations is not available yet on angular 2

Comment: Can you put your source code to https://plnkr.co/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay stagger animations are now supported in Angular 4 and is part of the new "query" function.

```
transition('* => *', [ // each time the binding value changes
    query(':leave', [
      stagger(100, [
        animate('0.5s', style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
    ]),
    query(':enter', [
      style({ opacity: 0 }),
      stagger(100, [
        animate('0.5s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ])
    ])
  ])
```

[Official documentation](https://angular.io/api/animations/stagger)

[Nice tutorial here](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/78/Creating-Stagger-Animations-in-Angular-4)